# Matlab - neighbouring clusters (in two different matrices)

Tags: matlab, comparison, cluster-analysis

Given two matrices A and B (same size - both containing only 1 and 0) and the associated structures from using `bwconncomp` on both of them.

How can I determine if clusters (position of which is contained in `CC.PixelIdcList`) in matrix A have neighbouring pixels with a position which matches the position of pixels in one of the clusters in matrix B?

I would like to make a list which contains id of each cluster in matrix A and the id of clusters neighbouring it (in matrix B) as well as the position of the neighbouring pixels that has position matching clusters in matrix B.

> ID cluster (from A) - ID clusters (from B) - positions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may be simpler to drop the use of `bwconncomp` and instead use `bwlabel` (or `bwlabeln` if this is N dimensional).

```
[labelA, numA] = bwlabel (mA);
[labelB, numB] = bwlabel (mB);

inter = labelA & labelB;

cluster_ind = unique (labelA(inter));

match_cluster = repmat ({[]}, numA, 1);
match_ind     = repmat ({[]}, numA, 1);
for idx = cluster_ind
  %% index with IDs from A to get...
  %% ... an array with IDs from B that intersect it
  match_clusters{idx} = unique (labelB(labelA == idx));
  %% ... linear indices for the elements that match something in B 
  match_ind{idx} = find (labelA === idx);
end
```

I'm assuming you have the original images before giving them to `bwconncomp`, if not, should be trivial to reconstruct a label image from its output.

Comment: Thank you this may work. However I have a problem. I would like to find if point surrounding clusters in matrix A are in positions corresponding to clusters in matrix B. I could use bwdist(A,'chessboard') to find the surrounding points and make a matrix C to compare. However the problem is that the separate clusters in matrix B may be grouped together if the clusters are close together.

Comment: @Mykje what do you mean with points surrounding cluster A? You don't need to use `bwdist`, that's very inneficient. You can dilate the image with an appropriated size SE, and subtract the original image to get the surrounding pixels. But that's a separate problem.

Comment: There are no overlap of the positions of the clusters in the two matrices. However, all clusters in matrix B will be located only one pixel (where they are closest) away from a cluster in matrix A. I need to know which clusters are adjecent and what the adjecent points are.

Comment: @Mykje then before calling `bwlabel` with the matrix A, expand it by one pixel with `mA = imdilate (mA, [0 1 0; 1 1 1; 0 1 0])` That will expand it one pixel on vertical and horizontal only. You can use `true (3)` instead to expand it on the diagonal as well.